# Want to know first character CharIndex

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In Below example i Want to know charindex of first character except spaces tabs newlines etc.

I am not able able to do that because `CHARINDEX()` function of SQL want character for index
 but in my string anyone comes dynamically.

```
Declare  @str varchar(100)
set @str='      test String'
```

in above case i want charindex of 't' (means first character of string)

```
  set @str='              String test'
```

in above case i want charindex of 'S' (means first character of string)

Anyone please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to come up with some kind of a regex. You can also have carriage return + line feed (linebreak) and tab -characters, which won't show correctly unless you do something like this:

```
DECLARE  @str VARCHAR(100)
SET @str=CHAR(9)+'      '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'test String'

SELECT CHARINDEX(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(9),' ')), @str);
SELECT SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,CHAR(13),' '),CHAR(10),' '),CHAR(9),' ')), @str), 1)
```

The characters are as follows:

1. CHAR(13) = carriage return
2. CHAR(10) = linefeed
3. CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) = standard newline characters
4. CHAR(9) = TAB

Comment: its not giving right charindex if we use space tabs and then space.

Comment: Hmm, true. The charindex value seems to vary oddly, in case of space + tab + space. IE. charindex can actually reduce in case of adding a tab after space. However, it still recognizes the placement of the first character correctly. Unfortunately I don't know and don't have the time to find out why it behaves that way, but it works for me regardless of which order I use for spaces, tabs and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Use Collation for Case sensitive.

```
Select CHARINDEX ( 'S',@str COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 1 )
```

Comment: The collation change will remove the trailing whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) to find the position of a character that is not one of a specific subset of excluded characters:

```
PATINDEX('%[^list of excluded characters]%', @str)
```

In your case, the excluded character list would consist of `CHAR(32)` (space), `CHAR(9)` (tab), `CHAR(13)` (carriage return), `CHAR(10)` (linefeed) and whatever else you mean by the `etc.`. Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @str varchar(100);
SET @str = '
  test string';
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^' + CHAR(32) + CHAR(9) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ']%', @str);
```

The `@str` in the above example begins with a newline (`CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`) followed by two spaces. Therefore, the output of the SELECT statement [would be this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39823):

```
----------
4
```

Comment: Use your string space and tab many times and see the result of position.
it gives wrong position.

Comment: @Navneet: Could you give an example? I'm not sure I understand what you mean. So far I've tried some combinations of spaces, newlines and tabs and it's all [worked well](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39878) for me.

Comment: in @str = 'test string' first give only one space it gives 2 that is fine 

now give one tab after space it gives 2 why ??
that is the issue

Comment: @Navneet: [Returns 3 for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/39898). Can you create a SQL Fiddle demo that shows wrong results using the method in my answer?